# Is incremental auth supported on OAuth2 Server module?

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

I'm working on a project where I would need to use OAuth2 server module and I've searched through the source-code of the module to check if incremental auth is supported i.e. adding scopes to old and valid tokens but couldn't find support for that. So, is there support for this feature in the module? And if someone has previously worked on adding that feature to the module; what was the work-around?